# Using Break to terminate for loop

Tags: c, file-handling

So, A very basic program in which I want to allow the user to enter up to 10 words to a text file.

**I want to make an exit clause such that If the user types a particular word, the program will stop**

I am trying to use `strcmp` and comparing "exit" with the word entered by the user.
If both match, then terminate. I know that if both are the same it returns 0, however I am unable to write:

```
{
char word[10];
FILE *fp;
int x;
int words = 0;

fp = fopen("c:\\CTEMP\\ExamProg1.txt", "w+");

{

    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)

    {
        printf("\nType the word you want to add. Type exit to terminate: ");
        scanf("%s", word);

        if (strcmp(word, "exit") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", word);
        words++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
 }

scanf_s("%d");

}
```

How can I proceed to break the program when exit is inputted, instead of having to insert 'exit' twice?

Comment: `if (strcmp(word, "exit")!=0)` You can use this so that, when not = to 0, proceed.

Comment: Does this even comlile? I don't think a function call result is an lvalue..

Comment: Yes it does compile. However my if statement including the `break` is wrong.

Comment: Post the definition of `word`.  Without that, the post is unclear.

Comment: Done, hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous things wrong with your code:

1. `scanf("%s", &word);` since a string is a pointer or array in and of itself, the address-of operator should not be present in a call to `scanf` where the scanned input is being read into a string. Just use: `scanf("%s", word);`.
2. `strcmp(word, "exit")=0`. The `=` operator is an assignment operator, not a comparison (what you want there is `strcmp(word, "exit") == 0`).  Your test for the word "exit" is failing because you are not properly examining the return value from `strcmp`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, however the program is still unable to break at this point. I have to type exit twice for it to exit. It looks like the first "exit" inputted only stops the program from executing the first `printf` statement.

Comment: Certainly you would not recommend `gets()`.  Why suggest `scanf("%s", word);` with its equally unlimited length problem?

Comment: @chux I was pointing out the incorrect usage of `scanf` in his code; that is not necessarily an endorsement of `scanf`

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely want to read the word with:

```
scanf("%99s", word); // where 99 == your buffer size - 1
                     //word is probably a pointer in your example so no &
```

(`scanf("%s",buf)`, like `gets(buf)`, is potentially a huge security hazard)
and then compare with `"exit"` like so:

```
 if (strcmp(word, "exit")==0)
```

Here's a dummy example that works:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[10];
    while(EOF!=scanf("%9s", buf)){ 
        printf("s=%s\n", buf);
        if(strcmp("exit",buf)==0){
            puts("<exit>");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    if(feof(stdin))
       puts("<EOF>");
    else
       puts("<ERROR>");

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. This code also works for me, however I wold like to implement a 'simpler' (?) version of this by using a normal break statement. by including `==0` I am still not terminating correctly.

Comment: @RyanRizzo `exit(0)` is just as normal as `break` is. Anyway, `break` will break the nearest enclosing loop, which would be the `for` loop in your example. Why that doesn't lead to program termination depends entirely on code you're not showing.